# ConnectionNotEstablished in Mongoid and Rspec in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I'm using Rails (5.1.0), Mongoid(6.1.0) and Rspec(3.6.0). I have removed active record from my app. Everything is working perfectly apart from tests. When I'm running rspec i get error:

```
Failure/Error: raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found." unless pool

 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
   No connection pool with 'primary' found.
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:930:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:516:in `create_fixtures'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:1028:in `load_fixtures'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:999:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:851:in `before_setup'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.6.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:607:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1894:in `with_suite_hooks'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 # /Users/kukicola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 # 
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

My rails_helper.rb file:

```
    # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

Mongoid.load!(Rails.root.join("config", "mongoid.yml"))

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
#ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!


RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  #config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  #config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  # config.before(:suite) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  # end
  #
  # config.before(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  # end
  #
  # config.before(:each, :js => true) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  # end
  #
  # config.before(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.start
  # end
  #
  # config.after(:each) do
  #   DatabaseCleaner.clean
  # end
end
```

And spec_helper.rb:

```
    # This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = "doc"
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

Comment: The error is coming from ActiveRecord. Make sure you fully removed it, `bundle`, and restart server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I had bad carrier_wave config which was loading active record